# Install SQL Server 2014 SP1 on VMWare workstation 12 player

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation, vmware

I am not able to install SQL 2014 SP1 on VMWare workstation 12 player.

Please review my post and give me some feedback on how to resolve the issue.
 Your input is greatly appreciated!

**Hardware information**

Desktop computer: DELL XPS 8900

Processor: Intel i7-6700

system type: 64 bits operating system

Memory: 16GB

Hard drive 1TB

OS: Windows 10 home edition

I installed three applications onto my desktop computer(local computer)

1. VMWare Workstation 12 player
2. Window Server 2012 Trial version
3. SQL Server 2014 SP1 (ISO) file

   I enabled .NET Framework 4.5 first in Windows Server 2012, then I enabled .NET Framework 3.5.

   Here are the steps I went through to install the SQL Server 2014
   I copied SQL Server 2014 ISO file onto virtual machine
   then extracted ISO file using WinRAR program
   run setup.exe file as a administrator.

   The set up process started, then it stopped at step 7 install Rules

   It showed me this message (see attached screenshot)

[image]

> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> **Cannot bind to the property or column IsNormalSelected on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember.**
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0x76F2B13F%25400x294A9FD9
>
> LinkID: 20476
>
> Product name: Microsoft SQL Server
>
> Message ID: 50000
>
> message source: setup.rll
>
> EvtType: 0x76F2B13F%400x294A9FD9

---

SQL Server set up log file copied form the virtual machine

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below

  Exit code (Decimal):           -2147024809

  Exit facility code:            7

  Exit error code:               87


  Exit message:                  Cannot bind to the property or column 
IsNormalSelected on the DataSource.  Parameter name: dataMember


  Start time:                    2016-04-07 01:44:59
  End time:                      2016-04-07 01:46:27
  Requested action:              Install
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0x76F2B13F%400x294A9FD9&EvtType=0x76F2B13F%400x294A9FD9

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  ATX2016
  Machine processor count:       1
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2012
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured


Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 

  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014

  Type:                          RTM

  Version:                       12

  Installation location:         C:\sql2014-install\SQLServer2014SP1-FullSlipstream-x64-ENU\x64\setup\

  Installation edition:          Evaluation


  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       1

Product Update Status:
  Success: KB 3058865

Product Updates Selected for Installation:
  Title:                         Microsoft SQL Server 2014  with SP1

  Knowledge Based Article:       KB 3058865

  Version:                       12.1.4100.0
  Architecture:                  x64
  Language:                      1033

  Update Source:                 Slipstream


User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    <empty>
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            true
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160407_014459\ConfigurationFile.ini

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160407_014459\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: System.ArgumentException
    Message: 
        Cannot bind to the property or column IsNormalSelected on the DataSource.
        Parameter name: dataMember
    HResult : 0x80070057
    Data: 
      HelpLink.EvtType = 0x76F2B13F@0x294A9FD9
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
        at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
        at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
        at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_BindingContextInternal(BindingContext value)
        at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.get_BindingContext()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
        at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.get_BindingContext()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnCreateControl()
        at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.HostControl.OnSelectedPageChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.UIHost.OnSelectedPageChanged()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.UIHost.set_SelectedPageIndex(Int32 value)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.NavigationButtons.nextButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than struggling with Evaluation Edition and the (limited) VMware Workstation Player, you could install Developer Edition instead. This is a supported configuration on the host OS (Windows 10 Home):

[Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx)

Developer Edition is functionally the same as Enterprise/Evaluation Edition, but with different licence terms (and no time limit, in the case of Evaluation).

Importantly, [Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition is now free](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/)

You could of course also install Developer Edition in a VM if you wish. I just think you will have fewer problems this way, and end up with what you need without the 180-day time limit.